# Any way to get better sound quality like using IcePower audio wizard in Windows 8.1?

Tags: sound, asus

Hi i know that is a strange question but anyway, i have an Asus X555lab that comes with windows, the thing is that Asus gives a small program called "Audio wizard", it have some options that improvement the audio quality,so the problem is that in linux this tool doesn't exist and the audio sounds notably worst, i wanna know if there exist an alternative or a tweak with the purpose to improve the sound quality of my laptop.

[Pic of the software(i found in Internet.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBgWT.jpg)
Sorry for my English, I'm not the best speaking it. x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PulseAudio Equalizer provides an effective equalizer with different presets and settings for Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Comment: Any good equalizer config?, I'm new on this of use equalizers :P

Comment: @IvanX507 That would heavily depend on your audio hardware. You'll have to play around, or hope that other people may have created profiles for your device.

Comment: I'm using the headphones preset, sounds pretty good :).

Comment: @IvanX507 You could upvote and select my answer as your answer :)

Comment: I can't upvote you, but i can select it like an answer :)